# How to add rewrite rule for Angular pushstate routing on AWS API Gateway

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, angular-routing

At [Angular Server Configuration section](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) you can read about how to configure fallbacks/url rewrites to index.html for different server setups e.g. an IIS (which I have done successfully).

I'm searching the internet (without any success so far) looking for a similar solution but for AWS API Gateway. Does anyone have any idea about how to make url rewrites in that tech stack? I.e I want to make url rewrite similar to this one (for IIS) but for AWS API Gateway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```